# Parsing a binary packet (from C) in Go

Tags: c, binary-data

Im writing a go application that listens for UDP packets over a network and parses them.

the udp packets are written in C and the struct definition (according to their docs)  is something like the below. (Please understand that new to C and networking in general)

```
typedef struct foo 
{
  int code;
  char seg[10];
  char sym[25];
  short type;
  long amtToday;
  long price;
  ...etc
} foo;
```

A sample network packet is something like the below

```
[233 3 0 0 99 100 101 95 102 111 0 0 0 0 55 52 51 57 0 69 69 68 49 48 50 48 74 65 78 50 48 50 49 0 0 58 254 127 0 0 1 0 166 58 254 127 0 0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 32 232 141 0 0 0 0 0 0 135 166 58 254 127 0 0 ... etc]
```

in short, im having trouble getting the right values after the `sym` field.

i read up a bit about struct alignment in C and guessing that im ignoring the padded values. But im a bit confused as to where the padding occurs

is it this

```
typedef struct foo 
{
  int code;
  char seg[10];
  **char pad[6];**
  char sym[25];
  **char pad[7];**
  short type;
  long amtToday;
  long price;
  ...etc
} foo;
```

i.e padding is added after each `char` field

or is it more like this

```
typedef struct foo 
{
  int code;
  char seg[10];
  char sym[25];
  **char pad[1];**
  short type;
  long amtToday;
  long price;
  ...etc
} foo;
```

the problem is that there is no way for me to determine if either of these are right at my end. I need to parse the entire struct before confirming - but unable to do so because of the padding issue

or am i heading in the wrong direction parsing this packet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The best way to convince yourself of how it works is probably to write C-code that computes the offsets:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct foo
{
    int code;
    char seg[10];
    char sym[25];
    short type;
    long amtToday;
    long price;
} foo;

int main() {
    // What are the memory offsets between individual struct members?
    foo x;
    printf(
        "code: %ld, seg: %ld, sym: %ld, type: %ld, amtToday: %ld, price: %ld\n",
        (long)&x.code - (long)&x,
        (long)&x.seg - (long)&x,
        (long)&x.sym - (long)&x,
        (long)&x.type - (long)&x,
        (long)&x.amtToday - (long)&x,
        (long)&x.price - (long)&x
    );

    // How much space does the struct take up if we create an array for it?
    foo y[2];
    printf("offset: %ld\n", (long)&y[1] - (long)&y[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
code: 0, seg: 4, sym: 14, type: 40, amtToday: 48, price: 56
offset: 64
```

*The offsets can depend on architecture and the compiler being used. If you are able to edit the C-program, adding explicit padding to the struct might be the best way to guarantee the same offsets on 32-bit and 64-bit systems.*

Comment: interesting - doesnt the `type` field being a short only take 2 bytes? why would it take 8 here?

Comment: So the interesting thing here, is that this doesn't depend on "type", but rather on "amtToday". Since amtToday is a long, it will always be 8-byte aligned. (unless you are on a 32-bit system). The order of your struct members will determine how tighly your struct can be packed in memory. For example alternating short and long is bad in terms of wasting space. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86

Comment: Thank you ! ill have a look at the article